# Error message on Xcode that I don't understand

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am getting an error message on my Xcode - Objective C.

Arithmetic on pointer to interface "UILabel", which is not constant size for this architecture and platform.

```
    if([self checkforwin]){
        NSString*winner = nil;

        if (playertoken==1)

         winner =@"Player 2 Wins";

        _result1 = _result1+1

        else if (playertoken==2)

            _result2 = _result2 +1

            winner =@"Player 1 Wins";
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Result"
                              message: winner
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [self resetboard];
        [_audioPlayer play];
        [alert show];
```

Any Ideas how to get rid of them??

The error shows on both the result1 and result2. Trying to add a score to my game.

Comment: Arithmetic on pointer to interface "UILabel", which is not constant size for this architecture and platform.@Mr.T

Comment: is result a uilabel? where is it declared ?

Comment: Check for semi-colon (;) also with _result1 & _result2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parenthesis while using condition. Also don't set string to `nil`, set it with empty string `@""`

```
if([self checkforwin]){

    NSString *winner = @"";

    if (playertoken==1) {

        winner =@"Player 2 Wins";
        _result1 = _result1 + 1;
    }
    else if (playertoken==2) {

        winner =@"Player 1 Wins";
        _result2 = _result2 + 1;
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Result"
                          message: winner
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [self resetboard];
    [_audioPlayer play];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: how do u know _Result is a integer type variable ?

Comment: @Mr.T there's applied increment on particular variable. So, I thought it might be an integer

Comment: I have changed the code to above @MS. but still showing the error

Comment: @user5806543 '_result1' is kind of UILabel ?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I declared as an Int @Mr.T so thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add 1 to the `UILabel`. You need an integer variable to do the increment. Either declare the _result 1 and 2 as `int` type variable or declare a int variable and increment it, and pass it to `UILabel` .text property

```
    _result1 = _result1+1
```

here _result1 must be a integer variable.

You need to something like:
Declare the result1 as int,

```
 @property(assign)  int result1;
```

and this line should be fine

```
      _result1=_result1+1;
```